# How to adjust watermark according to image?

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have done almost everything but i am facing one issue. I am creating multiple watermark at multiple locations. That is running fine but actually problem is when the image is having good resolution and watermark is looking very small. I want whatever the image resolution watermark should be zoom and visible here is my exec function and i am using laravel framework and i am using imagick library

```
$path = storage_path('app/images/TestImages/');
$mediumFileName = $path.str_random(4)."medium".str_random(4).".".$ext;
$watermarkImage = storage_path('watermark.png');
$saveWatermark = $path."image_watermark.jpg";
exec("convert $mediumFileName \( $watermarkImage -write MPR:wm \) \
-define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve            \
      -gravity NorthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity NorthEast -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity SouthEast -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity Center -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity SouthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite $saveWatermark");
```

Comment: Check the watermark and image dimensions before adding the same. You can use different watermark image sizes for different image sizes.

Comment: image is adding by user.. so it can be any size

Comment: watermark dimensions are 143*63 @informer

Comment: Yes and then you check the image size http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: so after what can i do ?

Comment: use http://image.intervention.io/api/insert . Much easier and cleaner than your exec()-command. From the info you gave, only you can know the dimensions.

Comment: @Chris i don't wnat use intervention package because intervention not maintain the dpi of an image that's why i am using imagemagick

Comment: I didn't know it wouldn't? either way, you will have to manually adjust the aspect ratio and create the widths and heights

Comment: Yes, intervention having main disadvantage of not supporting dpi of an image try upload and image of 300 dpi after uploading you see it will convert to 96 dpi

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Why not have a hi-res watermark and just scale it to say, 15% of the image width before applying it to the 4 corners?

Comment: so what is the better size of watermark any suggestion ? @MarkSetchell

Comment: if you have better idea can you update my code @MarkSetchell

Comment: I have no idea of your application, users, market, or aesthetics. I am just saying you could consider having a single watermark, suitably large for the largest image you are likely to encounter, and then scale it down to say 15% of whatever the current image is before applying it. That way it would cover a fixed proportion of every image in a uniform way.

Comment: I'll do it later for you if @Andreas doesn't - he seems on the right track.

Comment: Ok i am waiting for your reply @MarkSetchell

Comment: @Mark nope I have given up, there is too little information for us to help him. He only creates problems too when you try to help him. Instead of giving us some samples as "pictures usually are HD quality or 12 MPix" or whatever. And "I want the watermark to span across the full width or sit in the left corner" whatever. We can't help you if you don't help us! This is not directed at you mark. But I think you understood that. I hate autocorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a large watermark, with enough resolution for any picture as it is 1,000 pixels square.

[image]

Now, if we have a 1000x800 pixel image like this, we can resize the watermark to say 15% of that before compositing it (15% of 1000 is the 150 in the code):

```
convert image.jpg \( watermark.png -resize 150x -write MPR:wm \) \
          -gravity northwest -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity northeast -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity southwest -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.png
```

[image]

[image]

But, if we have a smaller image like this 400x300 image:

[image]

when we apply the watermark, we first resize it to 15% of 400, or 60:

```
convert image.jpg \( watermark.png -resize 60x -write MPR:wm \) \
          -gravity northwest -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity northeast -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity southwest -geometry +10+10 -composite         \
   MPR:wm -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.png
```

[image]

So, you need to get the size of your image how Andreas kindly showed you:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($mediumFileName);
```

and then multiply that by 0.15 (to get say 15%) and use that in your `-resize` parameter.

---

If the *"aside processing"* inside the parentheses above is upsetting or confusing, you can achieve the same result by loading up and resizing the watermark first, on its own, putting it into an MPR and then loading the main image and overlaying the MPR four times. It is just a different, maybe simpler, syntax:

```
convert watermark.png -resize 60x -write MPR:wm +delete image.jpg \
   MPR:wm -gravity northwest -geometry +10+10 -composite          \
   MPR:wm -gravity northeast -geometry +10+10 -composite          \
   MPR:wm -gravity southwest -geometry +10+10 -composite          \
   MPR:wm -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.png
```

Comment: thank you @Mark Setchell i am very happy you help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use imagesize and get the image size.
Choose a correct sized watermark an add that to the picture.

```
$path = storage_path('app/images/TestImages/');
$mediumFileName =  $path.str_random(4)."medium".str_random(4).".".$ext;
$watermarkImage = storage_path('watermark.png');

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($mediumFileName);

if ($height * $width < some Mpx){
    $watermarkImage = storage_path('watermarkSMALL.png');
} elseif($height*$width >some larger Mpx)
    $watermarkImage = storage_path('watermarkLARGE.png');
}

exec("convert 
$mediumFileName \( 
$watermarkImage -write     MPR:wm \) \
-define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve            \
  -gravity NorthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity NorthEast -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity SouthEast -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity Center -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
MPR:wm -gravity SouthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite $saveWatermark");
```

Comment: why you multiply height and width?

Comment: To get Mpix. It's a common way of describing picture size or camera "quality"

Comment: this is not good way to define the static Mpx in your if condition

Comment: Define static Mpix? You said it was user who added the image. How can it be static then?

Comment: i am talking about this < some Mpx

Comment: You are supposed to change the `some Mpix` to for example 2000000 (about HD quality). I thought that was clear when I wrote words in the code that it should be changed.

Comment: yes i know i have to put values instead of some px i understand but i want something like we have not to define static mpx

Comment: can you help me how to scale ?

Comment: Your question and description is so vague that it's hard to help you. And all you do is point out faults instead of helping. I add my close vote now.

Comment: Google it! I gave you one way to solve the problem. If you don't like it then make your own answer.

Comment: Ok @Andreas for help